# Why sometimes for Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitors Impendence is mentioned not ESR?

Tags: capacitor

while searching for Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitors in Didikey or Mouser, they mentioned ESR for some capacitors and Impedance for some capacitors, as both ESR and Impedance are different then why don't they show.
same happened when searching in vendor website/datasheet.

Comment: A cut and paste example would help a lot.

Comment: Supposedly because there's a lot of crap companies in a certain place of the world, making these components in particular. The kind of companies which got a line that spits out millions of electrolyte caps, but at the same time can't manage to come up with basic things like a proper data sheet, a web site, a sales dpt. The kind of stuff normal companies with >10 employees can manage. I'd specify some high quality brand like Panasonic as first source, then go looking for second source from there.

Comment: Also, Digikey or Mouser search filters are pretty shaky and often give incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

ESR and similarly ESL would let you calculate the entire impedance curve of the capacitor, however it takes longer to test components to make sure they are within that spec,

If your company is only selling to customers who care about impedance at 100KHz and 1MHz, you only test to those specifications, in reality the lower frequency values can usually let you reverse out an ESR range,

Impedance is the square root of (Xc<sup>2</sup> + Xl<sup>2</sup> + R<sup>2</sup>), so with a low enough frequency, XL does not have enough significance, leaving mostly R or your resistance,

Comment: Thanks, In my application Iam using 330uF bulk capacitor so I wanted to use through hole as they are cheap.

Comment: Thanks, In my application Iam using 330uF bulk capacitor so I wanted to use through hole as they are cheap. my DC-DC Converter uses 2MHz frequency, for this reason Iam looking for ESR value. I selected "ESW337M050AH4EA" I need minimum 50V rating capacitor. BUT I find very difficulty to find the part as they didn't gave ESR curve in there datasheet. Kindly advise how I should proceed to select through hole Aluminium Capacitor, my operating voltage and current is 24V and 6A. and 2MHz switching frequency.

Comment: 330uF and 2MHz are the wrong scale, you should have local decoupling at the switcher output like a small ceramic or tantalum at those switchmode frequencies, this will mean the larger bulk cap sees far lower frequencies.

Comment: Thanks,
my actual design is Input supply -- 330uf bulk cap---4.7uf cap---Isolated DC-DC Power Brick---100uF-- after that it has a 2Mhz switching buck regulator.
My doubt is for 330uF bulk capacitor, do I really need to check ESR value or even low impedance value capacitor is okay for my application.